# Fetch user interests and likes from Facebook along with images using Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to fetch Facebook logged in user's interests and likes, which I'm able to do.
But I'm not getting the image for pages liked by user or image for user interests.

The following code lets me fetch user likes:

```
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/likes"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          NSLog(@"User interests data: %@",result);
                      }];
```

which returns the following json data:

```
 data =     (
            {
        category = "Musician/band";
        "created_time" = "2014-08-08T05:09:56+0000";
        id = 9770929278;
        name = Adele;
    },
            {
        category = "Musician/band";
        "created_time" = "2014-08-08T05:02:09+0000";
        id = 5027904559;
        name = Shakira;
    }
 );
```

but, I want images for the pages liked. How can I do that?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of images you want? the profile picture of Page?

Comment: Yes, I want the profile picture of the liked page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute 1 more Graph API call for each for the likes:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/likes"
                         parameters:nil
                         HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                  completionHandler:^(
                                      FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error
                                      ) {
                      NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                      for(NSDictionary *liked in data) {
                         NSString *page_id = [liked objectForKey:@"id"];
                         [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/picture", page_id] parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(
                                      FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error
                                      ) {
                                         // Get your profile pic here
                                      }
                         }];
                      }
                  }];
```

It will return the public details of Page. See [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/picture) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for help.The 'id' returned from request 'me/likes', is not page-id probably. I need to get that first, before requesting 'page-id/picture'

Comment: Ooops, yes right.! But I could not get anything with page-id/picture. Rather I used page-id?fields=cover and then used source of cover image. Still unable to get profile pic of liked page.

Comment: If you read the documentation carefully, you have to add parameter `redirect=false` in order to return JSON response; else it will return an image instead

Comment: Right, I missed that. Thanks :)